# What's the difference between bathroom storage cabinets and vanity units?

Tags: bathroom, furniture, bathroom-fixtures, vanity

I am modifying my bathroom to suit my needs and I came across these two terms I could not comprehend. Can anyone explain the difference between bathroom storage cabinets and bathroom vanity units?

Answer (score 5):

Vanity units will have at least one compartment large enough for a standard sink bowl and its plumbing. It'll also usually have a fixed or detachable faux drawer front.

Comment: Also often a totally open back to make it easy to install plumbing.

Comment: Well, your cheaper units will. Higher grade and custom cabinets have backs for better and consistent appearance. I don't consider that a feature so much as a corporate cost-saving device.